# Уважаемые, помогите с Уважаемым Random.Range Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Random.Range теперь не работает?

[image: Random.Range]

Comment: Unity 2020.1.0b5

Comment: Возможно, Вы подключили пространство имен System. Тогда у Вас неопределенность - компилятор не понимает, вызываете ли вы System.Random или UnityEngine.Random.  Попробуйте явно указать **UnityEngine.Random.Range(.......)**

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский в С# рандом работает через `rnd.Next()` ))

Comment: @tender322 попробуйте использовать рандом напрямую, а не через переменную

Comment: @Methorn тут не при чём `rnd.Next()`, вы не совсем поняли то что сказал участник Александр Даниловский.

Comment: @Арман он имел ввиду рандом C# и рандом Unity

Comment: @Methorn Есть уже созданный класс в C# - `System.Random` и есть класс в Unity - `UnityEngine.Random`. Если просто в компиляторе добавить обе библиотеки - `using System; using UnityEngine;` и попробовать вызвать класс `Random` компилятор не поймёт какой именно класс вы хотите использовать и покажет [ошибку](http://prntscr.com/sckiu9).

Comment: @Арман понял, осознал